# CGRectOffset isn't working

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

For some reason, in my fresh iOS project, I can't get CGRectOffset to work for my UITextField (although I can't get it to work with any element I try).

In my viewController.h I have it assigned as

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *domainInput;
```

and in my viewController.h I'm trying to move the textField by performing

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _domainInput.frame = CGRectOffset(_domainInput.frame, 0, 500);
    NSLog(@"%f %f", _domainInput.frame.origin.x, _domainInput.frame.origin.y);
}
```

I'm printing the position to the log to prove that the position IS UPDATING, yet in the simulator, there's no movement.

I first noticed the bug when trying to run animateWithDuration on the position. When I try to put the `_domainInput.frame = CGRectOffset(_domainInput.frame, 0, 500);` inside an animeWithDuration function, it starts the animation from the offset position and moves back to the original position!

I've been racking my brain for a few hours trying to figure this out, I feel like it must be something simple I'm doing wrong. I even started a new project with just a text field, and I can't get it to move using CGRectOffset.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: you may need to know about the view-lifecycle that the final frame is determined _after_ the view is in the navigation stack (or its superview goes there) then the frame will be adjusted for the current `UIWindow` instance; _before_ it goes to the navigation stack, the `frame` is temporarily loaded from the _xib_, and it may be overridden for adjusting the `UIWindow` in accordance with either auto-layout or auto-resize mask settings. long story short: the `–viewDidLoad` method called _before_ the view has any chance to become a part of the view-hierarchy. it is not a bug.

Comment: FYI: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html

Comment: Also, it doesn't make much sense to set `frame` when you properly use autolayout.

Comment: @holex, I should have mentioned that before it was in the `viewDidLoad`, it was in a function that was trigged upon hitting return from inside the textField. That's when I was testing it with `animateWithDuration`, and I noticed that it would first set the position to the destination position, then revert back to the original position. I only moved it to the `viewDidLoad` to save me from having to keep entering text and hitting return.

Comment: @iGARET, in that case, maybe _A-Live_'s comment leads you to the solution – you cannot change directly the `frame` or `center` if the auto-layout is `ON`.

Comment: Oh boy, this is exactly what I was expecting, a simple solution. I don't know why it never occurred to me before, but thanks for bringing it to my attention! It seems to be working now. Thanks @A-Live and @holex!